# What should I use between "triple" vs. "all"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, determiners, triple-thrice

If I have 2 pens and I want to say all of them are green, I can say "Both of them are green" but if I have 3 pens should I use "Triple of them are green" or "All of them are green"?

Comment: Is that you, Dr Seuss?

Comment: Of note, _triple_ compares to _double_, not _both_. "Triple of them are green" is wrong for the same reason "double of them are green" is wrong.

Comment: @Ed: who is Dr. Seuss?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Seuss

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could go with any of the following:

*All 3 of my pens are green,*

*All (of) my 3 pens are green,*

*My 3 pens are all green,*

The word [*triple*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/triple) as an adjective means:

1. Three times bigger in size or amount
2. Having three parts or including three people or things, for example:

   *a triple murder*

   *a triple heart bypass*

When used as a verb, it means:

1. To cause (something) to become three times as great or as many
2. To become three times as great or as many

In mathematics:

to *triple the number 4* is equivalent to *multiplying 4 by 3*,

written numerically as:  (4 + 4 + 4) or (4 x 3) = 12

Source: M-W

Hope that helps.

Comment: The closest construction to "Both of them are green." is "All three of them are green."

Comment: Yes, @PeterShor; you're quite right.

Comment: @Peter Shor: That's exactly what i said, in one sentence. I don't know why long answers are more attractive here.

Comment: @zizi: "All my three pens" is different from "All three of my pens," and I believe the second one is quite a bit more natural in English. You can say "All my pens" and "My three pens," but when you put these constructions together, you need to add an *of*. I don't know why.

Comment: @Peter, it's because "All my pens" really needs an 'of', too ("All *of* my pens"). I think omitting the 'of' really only sounds OK because of a certain long-running TV show by the name of *All My Children*.

Comment: @Martha: the same thing happens with *All the pens,* and *[All the king's men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty)* has been around for much longer than *All My Children.* Here, for example, "All the four king's men" is wrong, although "All four king's men", "All the king's men," "All four of the king's men," and "All of the four king's men" are all acceptable. I think it's because the two number adjectives, *all* and *four,* don't like being separated.

Comment: (continued) although note that "All the four kings' men," where four modifies kings and not men, is fine. Here *all* and *four* don't mind being separated because they're modifying different nouns.

Comment: This is an overall good answer but I think it has a flaw in that the phrasing of the fifth line might make it easy to conflate with how the concept of thirds are presently taught. I'm not sure entirely how to fix that at present though.

Answer (score 2):

You can say "all my 3 pens are green" to mention the number of your pens and their color, simultaneously.

Comment: "Each of my 3 pens are green" sounds more natural to me.

Comment: @MrHen: "Each of my 3 pens _is_ green"

Answer (score 1):

I have three pens - all green.