# Is "both" singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, determiners, quantifiers

Is the following correct?

> Both of these essentially act as a WebKit wrapper.

Or should it be the following?

> Both of these essentially acts as a WebKit wrapper.

[Context](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1d10560c-7257-4881-a31e-4e1a09b00032/view-source).

Comment: Related: [How does “each” change “are” to “is”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24846/how-does-each-change-are-to-is)

Comment: Not sure if it's plural or single.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word *both* is a determinative (in the terminology of *CGEL*). Determinatives are not per se singular or plural (except *these* and *those*), but they select singular or plural nouns. When *both* appears without the head noun, as it does here, there is a fusion of functions and it becomes both the determiner and the head of the plural NP. The verb then agrees with the plural NP.

[image: syntax tree showing partitive construction with *both*] (ignore the clumsy grey line above Head)

Comment: bro appreciate your efforts but everybody loves simple and straight-to-head explanations.

Comment: So it's plural in this case?

Comment: When you say *we are*, *we* is plural and *are* agrees with it, but it doesn't make sense to say that *are* is plural because it's not a noun. In the same way, it doesn't make sense to talk about *both* being singular or plural because it's not a noun.So, if you just want to know what kind of verb agreement to use, then use the form that agrees with plural subjects. But if OP actually wants to know if *both* is plural or singular, there is no answer. The question is malformed.

Answer (score 49):

It acts only like plural because, unlike *each*<sup>1</sup> and *none*<sup>2</sup>, *"both"* refers to all of the elements and not to one of them.

Read these examples from the [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/both):

- *Both of us were tired.*  - and not - **Both of us was tired.*
- *Both of them were French* - and not - **Both of them was French*.

---

(1) - [Each](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/each) is usually singular: "*each of us **knows** about you*".
(2) - [None](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/none_1) can be both singular or plural: "*none of us **is/are** going home.*" (the singular form is considered formal in BrE).

<sup>Note: for more accurate explanations, visit the links, otherwise if I add too much info, this answer gets off topic.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

> Both of these essentially act as WebKit wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

*Both* is definitely plural.

> Both me and my brother are doing our best at school

[Here's an explanation on using *both*](http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/both.htm). Although this explanation is irrelevant to the OP's question, none of the examples there uses *both* as singular.

[And here it is stated explicitly](http://www.english4today.com/englishgrammar/grammar/Determiners11a.cfm).

Comment: Both my brother and I are not doing so well in school, especially English. You have to use 'I', and you really should put yourself last in a list.

Comment: Both links are (!) broken. The first is 404 and the second redirects to the main page.