# Use of "both" ("singular" vs "plural", "nominative" vs "oblique")

Tags: grammatical-number, nominative-vs-oblique

I know that this is a possible duplicate of [Is "both" singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27327/is-both-singular) but the question was asked and answered more than 6 years ago and I don't want to reopen a question of 6 years ago. Also, my doubt is not solved by the answers nor by the proposed links.

So, here we are. Should I say...

- ... *both me and my brother is male* **or** *both me and my brother are male* **or** *both I and my brother is male* **or** *both I and my brother are male* ?
- ... *both me and my brothers is male* **or** *both me and my brothers are male* **or** *both I and my brothers is male* **or** *both I and my brothers are male* ?

I know that this can be an easy question for an English native speaker but it's not for me.

**Remark**: The old question was about the use of *both of* so it's slightly different from mine. Also, there is an answer to my case (e.g. *Both me and my brother are doing our best at school*) but I think that in the comments someone suggests that this answer is wrong.

Comment: Note that _males_ sounds a bit off.  _Males_ normally means _male animals_. Male humans are called _men_. You could very well use the adjective _male_, but then it never gets an -s.

Comment: I didn't know that _male_ could be used only as adjective in the human context. Do you think that I should modify the question?

Comment: The question sounds ridiculous. 'My brother is male' surely doesn't need stating. // 'Both Jo and Peter are female' shows the natural way of phrasing this, though using the plural noun 'females' is not ungrammatical. 'Both me and my friend/s are male' is often used informally.

Comment: @giusva _Male_ can be used as an adjective for humans. I was talking about the use as a _noun_, the way you used it in your examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's an example. It doesn't need to be a serious example. It is used only to check the rules of singular/plural and nominative/oblique. It's obvious that a brother implicitly is also a male.

Comment: @oerkelens I know that I used _male_ as noun. In fact I point out that I didn't know that _male_ could be used **only** as adjective, that means that I didn't know that it cannot be used as noun.

Comment: I hate when someone negatively votes a question without giving feedback about why it is bad in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In colloquial speech, it is common to say, "Me and my brother are ..." However, it is technically incorrect as both *my brother* and *I* are the subjects of this sentence. It is more grammatically correct to say:

"Both my brother and I are male."

A good way to catch this common error is to break apart the compound subject and try each one alone in the sentence (with the appropriate verb):

"My brother is male." *CORRECT*

"Me am male." *WRONG*

"I am male." *CORRECT*

As oerkelens suggests, you can use *male* as an adjective. I also switched the positions of the subjects because it sounds more natural to put oneself at the end of a compound subject.

Comment: Did you changed the order of the subjects in order to avoid cacophony or for a specific reason? I mean, if it's correct to say _Both my brother and I are male_ is also correct _Both I and my brother are male_? If not, please tell me why.

Comment: Both statements are grammatically correct. To my ear, *I and my brother* sounds either antiquated or poetic, but there's no rule saying you can't order it that way. Here's a short post which talks about this very issue: https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/01/me-and-you.html

Comment: I understand now. In the link there is also a reference to _politeness_. I am always surprised when I find new examples of how courtesy is intrinsic in English and not an optional thing.