# "Each of these is" vs. "each of these are"

Tags: grammar, american-english

> Each of these CDFIs are finding solutions for communities that lack
>   access to traditional financial products and services, and the NEXT
>   Awards will accelerate their success.

OR

> Each of these CDFIs is finding solutions for communities that lack
>   access to traditional financial products and services, and the NEXT
>   Awards will accelerate their success.

The difference is, the first one uses "CDFIs are" and the 2nd sentence uses "CDFIs is"

Which one is correct? Any why?

Comment: Much related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24846/how-does-each-change-are-to-is. Possibly a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the linking ", and". Possibly replace it with a period?

Given:

"Each of these fish are tasty." - improper.

"Each of these fish is tasty." - proper.

Then:

"Each of these fish are tasty, and they look good too." - improper.

"Each of these fish is tasty, and it looks good too." - improper.

"Each of these fish is tasty, and looks good too." - proper.

"Each of these fish is tasty, and they look good too." - maybe proper, but awkward.

"Each of these fish is tasty. They look good too." - proper, and less awkward.

So try:
"Each of these CDFIs is finding solutions for communities that lack access to traditional financial products and services. The NEXT Awards will accelerate their success."

Or maybe, sneakily get rid of "their"?

"Each of these CDFIs is finding solutions for communities that lack access to traditional financial products and services, and the NEXT Awards will accelerate this success."

Comment: I still don't like the way is sounds in this sentence.  To me it is awkward, even if it is proper.  BTW, thanks so much for the details and also for providing different solutions to this.  :)

Comment: To me, it sounds better to say `Each of my friends are on their way over`, instead of `Each of my friends is on their way over`.

Comment: +1 And suggested/added "Each of these fish is tasty, and looks good too." as proper.

Answer (score 1):

If each CDFI is individually finding one or more solutions, I'd have to say the second, since *is* matches *each*.

Answer (score -1):

Grammar freaks will argue you should use "is" because it is proper, but I agree it is more fluent to use "are" and sounds less awkward. I think about the sentence, "these are tasty fish" instead of "these is tasty fish" lol