# Do "to be" and "to have" work differently from each other with "each"?

Tags: verb-agreement

Notes for context: I am a native BrEng speaker. I have read ["Each of these is" vs. "each of these are"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126726/each-of-these-is-vs-each-of-these-are), [How does "each" change "are" to "is"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24846/how-does-each-change-are-to-is), and [What should I use between "triple" vs. "all"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24777/what-should-i-use-between-triple-vs-all) and I understand the general concept of "Each of them is" and how "each" always takes the singular.

Reading my daughter's bedtime story this evening, I came across the phrase "They each have a bag of equipment". It made me wonder why the following seems naturally (to me at least) to be true:

> (Correct) Each of them has an X
>   (Correct) They each have an X
>   (Correct) Each of them is a Y
>   (Incorrect?) They each are a Y

I would never say (to use the examples from one of the posts I linked) "I have three pens. They each are green.", but "I have three pens. They each have a lid." is fine.

Is "to have" different from "to be" when it comes to using it with "each"?

Comment: Aside: some of these kids' stories are pretty mind-numbing. Got to think about *something* while reading them out loud! :-)

Comment: When used adverbially like this, _each_ means ‘per [noun]’, which makes sense with _have_ (distributive possession), but not with _be_ (distributive being?). You can see this even more clearly if you move it to the end of the sentence: “The kids have three apples each” vs. “*The kids are boys each”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, that makes perfect sense. If you make it an answer rather than a comment I can upvote and accept!

Comment: Related: [“…programs that each perform…” vs “…programs that each performs…”: which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12387)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Janus Bahs Jacquet answered this perfectly in a comment but didn't respond to my request to re-post the comment as an answer, so I'm re-posting it here as a CW answer.

> When used adverbially like this, each means ‘per [noun]’, which makes
>   sense with have (distributive possession), but not with be
>   (distributive being?). You can see this even more clearly if you move
>   it to the end of the sentence: “The kids have three apples each” vs.
>   “*The kids are boys each”.

Answer (score -2):

I understood "is" is singular and "are" is plural.

*Each* one of them *is*

*All* of them *are*

Comment: I've edited my answer for formatting and it appears to not be separating onto separate lines.

Comment: You're answering a different question from the one I asked. I know that each as the subject of a verb takes the singular, as I said in the context at the start of the question.

Answer (score -3):

The number 4 is indeed incorrect. They can all each have the same thing but to be the same thing, only each of them can be it, or all of them are it.

Comment: You're answering a different question from the one I asked. I know that each as the subject of a verb takes the singular, as I said in the context at the start of the question.

Comment: I think you misread my answer. Not only I do not see any apparent formulated question, but there is also no difference opposing ' They each are green' and 'they each have a lid', in the sense both are in the same plural forms agreement.

Comment: I think you could have misread the general aspect of my answer. There is nonetheless no difference opposing ' They each are green' and 'they each have a lid, Both verbs 'to be' and 'to have' are in the plural form. What is your question?

Comment: My question is "Is "to have" different from "to be" when it comes to using it with "each"?" as I wrote in the final line, and in the subject of the question. The difference between "they each are green" and "they each have a lid" is that the former sounds all kinds of wrong, whereas the latter sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: Your question seemed very much about usage the usage 'each.' are there any difference between the verbs to be and to have really your question? I

Comment: I apologize if the topic around your question seemed to me very much about usage the usage of each. Nevertheless, are there any differences between the verbs to be and to have" really your or even a question?